# Access diagonal in multi-index

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a rank-3 multi-index. I would like to extract the "diagonal" in the first two indices. I.e. extract the values where the first two indices are equal to each other, whereas the third index takes all possible values.

Here is an example code, that generates such a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

d = 0
e = 1
for A in xrange(3):
    for B in xrange(3):
        for C in xrange(2):
            df = df.append(dict(A=A, B=B, C=C, d=d, e=e), ignore_index=True)
            d += 2
            e += 2

df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)
df.sortlevel(inplace=True)
print df
```

The DataFrame then looks like this:

```
        d   e
A B C
0 0 0   0   1
    1   2   3
  1 0   4   5
    1   6   7
  2 0   8   9
    1  10  11
1 0 0  12  13
    1  14  15
  1 0  16  17
    1  18  19
  2 0  20  21
    1  22  23
2 0 0  24  25
    1  26  27
  1 0  28  29
    1  30  31
  2 0  32  33
    1  34  35
```

I would like to extract the rows where `A`, and `B` are equal (in an efficient way, as the real DataFrame has 100-1000 values for `A`, and `B`). Given the above example, I want to extract the following DataFrame:

```
        d   e
A B C
0 0 0   0   1
    1   2   3
1 1 0  16  17
    1  18  19
2 2 0  32  33
    1  34  35
```

I have tried it with the following code.

```
ind = np.diag_indices(3) + (slice(None),)
df_diag = df.loc[ind, slice(None)]
print df_diag
```

It prints:

```
        d   e
A B C
0 0 0   0   1
    1   2   3
  1 0   4   5
    1   6   7
  2 0   8   9
    1  10  11
1 0 0  12  13
    1  14  15
  1 0  16  17
    1  18  19
  2 0  20  21
    1  22  23
2 0 0  24  25
    1  26  27
  1 0  28  29
    1  30  31
  2 0  32  33
    1  34  35
```

As you can see it just selects all the data.

My question is, how can I extract the rows where `A`, and `B` have the same values in an efficient way from a DataFrame such as the one given above.

## EDIT: Benchmark on answers

Using the following code to generate a larger dataframe:

```
numAB = 100
numC = 10
num = numAB**2 * numC
A = np.repeat(np.arange(numAB), numAB * numC)
B = np.tile(np.repeat(np.arange(numAB), numC), numAB)
C = np.tile(np.arange(numC), numAB**2)
d = np.arange(num) * 2
e = d + 1
dflarge = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=A, B=B, C=C, d=d, e=e)).set_index(['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

I tested @Alexander's answer:

```
%%timeit
res = pd.concat([dflarge.loc[pd.IndexSlice[n, n, :], :] for n in dflarge.index.levels[0]])
```

Resulting in:

```
10 loops, best of 3: 96.7 ms per loop
```

And I tested @Fabio's answer:

```
%%timeit
df2 = dflarge.reset_index()
res = df2[df2['A']==df2['B']]
res.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)
```

Resulting in:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 8.72 ms per loop
```

The latter is about 10 times faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first reset the index of the dataframe with:

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

then do the filter to select what you want:

```
d = df[df['A']==df['B']]
```

Finally set the index again:

```
d.set_index(['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)
```

This returns:

```
        d   e
A B C        
0 0 0   0   1
    1   2   3
1 1 0  16  17
    1  18  19
2 2 0  32  33
    1  34  35
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the first and second level of the index are identical, you can use `IndexSlice` using the contents of the first level.

```
>>> pd.concat([df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[n, n, :], :] for n in df.index.levels[0]])
Out[278]: 
        d   e
A B C        
0 0 0   0   1
    1   2   3
1 1 0  16  17
    1  18  19
2 2 0  32  33
    1  34  35
```